# The difference between waterfall model and object oriented model?

Tags: oop, model, methodology, waterfall

can I know what is the different between waterfall model and object oriented model?  Since the book and web dint provide much  info about it. Thankyou.

Comment: I don't think you can compare the two models directly. The waterfall model is targeting the software development process as a whole, while object orientation is a programming paradigm. But maybe you meant something else?

Comment: i meant the different something like definition, concept, and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An appropriate comparison would be to iterative development or one of the Agile methodologies.

**The waterfall model** is the traditional model of the software life cycle. The waterfall model is *sequential*. The approach for waterfall model is:

> Analyze, Design, Build, Test, Maintenance.

Waterfall model concentrates on **software development cycle**.

**The object oriented model** focuses on **software design** and **its implementation**.

> Classes, Objects, Polymorphism, Inheritance, Coupling, Data dependencies.